# Problem with the VBA Code- Unprotect workbook with hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i'm with a problem on my VBA code which it's not unprotecting my workbook with some sheets that are hidden. One hypothesis that I thought, was to unhide all sheets, unprotect the workbook and after that unhidde all sheets that were initially hidden.

I've already tried to built an code, but the step of hidde all sheets that were initially hidden it's not working!

Please, could y'all help me guiding me why it's not working!?

```
Sub UnlockSheets()
' Define the password to unlock the tabs
Dim password As String
password = InputBox("Enter the password")
   
' Collection to store the original visibility state of the tabs
Dim originalState As New Collection

' Reference to the currently active worksheet
Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
Set activeSheet = ActiveSheet

' Loop through all the tabs in the workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' Check if the tab is protected with a password
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        ' Store the original visibility state of the tab
        originalState.Add ws.Visible, ws.Name
        ' Show the tab before unprotecting it (only if it was hidden)
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Or ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
        
        ' Activate the tab before unprotecting it
        ws.Activate
        
        ' Unprotect the tab using the provided password
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Unprotect Password:=password
        On Error GoTo 0
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=password
    End If
Next ws

' Return to the originally active worksheet
activeSheet.Activate

' Hide the tabs again (if they were originally hidden)
Dim tab As Variant
For Each tab In originalState
    On Error Resume Next
    If originalState(tab) = xlSheetHidden Or originalState(tab) = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        Dim newTabName As String
        newTabName = Replace(tab, oldTabName, newTabName)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(newTabName).Visible = originalState(tab)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next tab
End sub
```

Also i have another doubt, i have this same code apllied to an button. when I play the macro from the button it returns me an error 1004 on the line wb.Unprotect Password:=password' *****.
When i play the code from itself, it works! There's any logic, for this!?
[image]

Comment: What happens when you remove the `On Error Resume Next` line?

Comment: Workbook protection can be removed using the Unprotect method, regardless of whether any sheets are hidden or very hidden.

Comment: Where is this code located (in which module?)? Please share the complete code from `Sub...` to `...End Sub`. Also, in more detail, share what the code is supposed to do and what it is doing at the moment (is there an error?). Since there is only one workbook, the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), you shouldn't use `ActiveWorkbook` especially not when looping through the worksheets before unprotecting it. Unprotect it before the loop.

Comment: Hello all,
@VBasic2008, It doesn't returns me any error, it just unhide all hidden sheets, then unprotect it like expecting, but the code can't hide the initially hidden sheets.
There is one situation that when the code can't access the hidden sheet to unprotect it, it returns me an 1004 error on the line: 
`ws.Unprotect Password:=Password`

Answer (score 0):

### Unprotect Workbook and Worksheets

- On my end (*Windows 10 64-bit, M365*), it looks like you can unprotect a **worksheet** without even unprotecting the **workbook**.
- The visibility doesn't matter. You cannot change it while the **workbook** is protected. Maybe that was the case you got an error!?
- The behavior may be different for different 'types' of protection.
- Try to play with the following out-commenting and uncommenting the lines designated with `*****` and hiding the worksheets to prove me wrong.

```vb
Sub UnlockSheets()
    
    Dim Password As String: Password = InputBox("Enter the password")
       
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    If wb.ProtectStructure Then
        Debug.Print "The workbook was protected."
        wb.Unprotect Password:=Password ' *****
    Else
        Debug.Print "The workbook was not protected."
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.ProtectContents Then
            Debug.Print "Worksheet """ & ws.Name & """ was protected."
            ws.Unprotect Password:=Password ' *****
        Else
            Debug.Print "Worksheet """ & ws.Name & """ was not protected."
        End If
    Next ws
    
    wb.Protect Password, True, False ' *****
    
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Vbasic2008
it worked pretty well the code you did it! Thank you!
I have another doubt in the same situation, when I block the sheets with the code below, it doesn't work your code that you just did, is there something wrong with it?

`Sub lockSheets()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Password As String
    password = "a"
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=Password
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False
    Next ws
End Sub`

Comment: Dear, i have another question
i have this same code apllied to an button. when I play the macro from the button it returns me an error 1004 on the line `wb.Unprotect Password:=password' *****`.
When i play the code from itself, it works! There's any logic, for this!?